# In-app purchase receipt not sent to server when production

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I have been trying to upload a new version of my app containing **non-renewing In-app Purchases** with no success. It has been revoked for almost two months and i cannot find the problem.

When i'm testing with a **sandbox** account the purchase goes to my server, i authenticate the receipt and then update my user's status. But when my app goes to review, the reviewer says that my app doesn't deliver user's paid content, but i get not single attempt on my server.

I have made some changes on my Objective-C code hoping that maybe the error could be the timeout, which now i changed to **45.0 seconds**. How long it is supposed to be?

I also made some changes to my server code that check if the purchase have been made by a **sandbox or production account**.

So... this is the method called after `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`.

```
#pragma mark pagamento
-(void)completarTransacao:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transacao
{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]  appStoreReceiptURL]];

    if (!receipt)
    {
       receipt = transacao.transactionReceipt;
    }

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:NSLocalizedString(@"Efetuando assinatura...", nil)];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@assinaturaplano/", [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:configuracoes_plist] objectForKey:@"Dominio"]]] cachePolicy:nil timeoutInterval:45.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:[NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://temp"]]]];

    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"receipt=%@&transactionIdentifier=%@&origem=%@", [receipt.base64Encoding urlencode], transacao.transactionIdentifier, [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[home_documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"compra"]] objectForKey:@"origem"]];

   [request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[postString UTF8String] length:postString.length]];

   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *erro)
   {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        if ([(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode] == 200 || [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode] == 201)
        {
            // SUBSCRIPTION CONFIRMED
            [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:NSLocalizedString(@"Assinatura efetuada com sucesso!", nil)];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"atualizarGold" object:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            // SUBSCRIPTION NOT CONFIRMED
            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:NSLocalizedString(@"Assinatura não efetuada. Tente novamente.", nil)];
        }

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transacao];
    }];
}
```

My purchase method always goes to else when in review.

**Review response**

> Reasons
>   2.2: Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected
>   ----- 2.2 ----- We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8 and iPhone 5s running iOS 8, on
>   both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the
>   App Store Review Guidelines. In App Purchase does not complete. After
>   users tap on the In App Purchase, enter the Apple ID and password and
>   confirm the purchase, an error message is produced. The steps to
>   reproduce are:
>   1. launch app
>   2. sign in with the provided credentials
>   3. select 'Gold Membership'
>   4. tap '7 days'
>   5. enter the user's Apple ID and password
>   6. confirm purchase
>   7. error message appears

What am i doing wrong? Why does it work only though sandbox?

Comment: Have you checked to see which HTTP status code you are getting?

Comment: The problem was that i was searching for the receipt info in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

To find the receipt info i did the following:

```
// Transaction: SKPaymentTransaction
// storeURL: Sandbox - https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt | Production - https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
-(void)validateTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction storeURL:(NSString *)url
{
     receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]  appStoreReceiptURL]];

     if (!receipt)
     {
         receipt = transacao.transactionReceipt;
     }

     NSError *error;

     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

     [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

     [request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0], @"password" : @"yourpassword"} options:0 error:&error]];

     [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {        
         if (!connectionError)
         {
              NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

              if ([[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"status"] intValue] == 0)
              {
                  NSDictionary *purchaseInfo;

                  NSArray *inApp = [[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"receipt"] objectForKey:@"in_app"];

                  if (inApp)
                  {
                      for (NSDictionary *receptDictionary in inApp)
                      {
                          if ([[receptDictionary objectForKey:@"transaction_id"] isEqualToString:transacao.transactionIdentifier])
                          {
                              purchaseInfo = receptDictionary;

                              break;
                          }
                      }
                  }

                  // The recent has been found
                  // Send it to your server
              }
              else
              {
                  switch ([[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"status"] intValue])
                  {
                  case 21003:
                          // Receipt not authenticated

                          [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

                          break;
                  case 21005:
                          // Server not available 

                          break;
                 case 21007:
                          // Sandbox receipt send it to sandbox server
                          [self validateTransaction:transaction storeURL:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
                          break;
                 case 21008:
                          // Production receipt send it to production
                          [self validateTransaction:transaction storeURL:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
                          break;
                  }
              }
          }
          else
          {
              // It was not possible to connect AppStore
          }
      }];
 }
```

Comment: @user337658 i hope it helps.